# Как обернуть img в div?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modal-name").on("click", function() {
    let images=JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-img'));
    $.each(images, function( i, val ) {
       $('<img>', {
          id: 'modal-img',
          class: '',
          src: val 
       }).appendTo('.modal-img');
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Как обернуть каждый img в div?

Comment: `$("<img>",...).wrap("<div>").appendTo(..)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял то так

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modal-name").on("click", function() {
    let images=JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-img'));
    $.each(images, function( i, val ) {
      $('.modal-img').append(`<div><img id='modal-img-${i}' src='${val}'></div>`);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: так это тоже самое, что и у меня. Мне нужно получить код в таком виде: <div><img src=""></div>

Comment: Правил можете попробовать так?

Comment: Спасибо, работает!